# How to map relational database to OWL?

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, protege4

I am trying to map relational database to OWL
Here are my 2 tables
student(student_id,student_name,course_id)
course(course_ID,course_name)

```
+----+--------+-----------+    
| id | name   | course_id |  
+----+--------+-----------+     
|  1 | Adam   |         5 |   
|  2 | Michael|         2 |    
+----+--------+-----------+   
+-----------+-------------+    
| course_id | course_name |   
+-----------+-------------+      
|         2 | DM          |    
|         5 | WEBIR       |  
+-----------+-------------+
```

Now course_id is the foreign key in student table referencing
course_id in course table.I created ontology(defined the schema) using Protege 4.3

I am trying to insert data into the OWL file as instances using Jena API.
In ontology, columns which are not foreign keys were mapped to datatype 
properties and foreign keys are mapped to object property as per this paper[(mapping relational to OWL(section 4.4.4))](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.8189&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
I am adding the tuples as instances to the student and course classes in Jena.
If foreign key is object property how can i use it to uniquely determine relation.
Here is the jena code I have used to add data as instances to owl file created in Protege.

```java
    for (student std : studlist) {
        Individual stud = stud_ont.createIndividual(nspace + "student/"
                + std.getStudent_id());
        stud.addProperty(stud_id, std.getStudent_id());
        stud.addProperty(stud_name, std.getStudent_name());
        stud.addProperty(reln, std.getCourse_id());
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(
                "/home/owlDM/newedu.owl");
        m.writeAll(p, "RDF/XML", null);
        p.close();
    }
    for (course crs : courselist) {

        Individual cour = course_ont.createIndividual(nspace + "course/"
                + crs.getCourse_name());
        cour.addProperty(course_course_name, crs.getCourse_name());
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(
                "/home/owlDM/newedu.owl");
        m.writeAll(p, "RDF/XML", null);
        p.close();
    }
```

Here "reln" is the object property(functional) for which I am adding course_id(values) which is the foreign key.
But would it help in relating two instances ,meaning
Suppose I need to infer "Adam has taken WebIR Course".

How can my object property can replace foreign key value in relational to uniquely
join two tuples of two classes?
Please suggest,Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

"The [D2RQ](http://d2rq.org/) Platform is a system for accessing relational databases as virtual, read-only RDF graphs".

You might want to have a look at that

Comment: thanks for your response.Using D2RQ was my first approach,D2RQ just converts my database to an RDF file.I wanted to add  object properties to bring about semantic enrichment using OWL(Protege) which I was not able to do using D2RQ.

Comment: Import the RDF file in your ontology (or both the RDF file and your ontology in a third ontology) and use that with a reasoner in order to get reasoner backed answers to your queries.

Comment: [ONT-D2RQ](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-d2rq) is a special fork for OWL2