# How to create ontology specifically .owl file using Jena

Tags: jena, ontology

Hi I am new to Ontology.

How can I create .owl file using Apache Jena. Actually I have some data which I want to place in ontology .owl file but I am not sure how to create .owl file.

Can someone please point to example/url to create the ontology file using Apache Jena

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what format is your data currently?

Comment: [Writing RDF with Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-output.html) gives some examples in this regard. Use `RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, model, RDFFormat.RDFXML)`.

Comment: Actually I have data in DB and want to build ontology for POC purpose. The Data is in following format :
 Test1 :
    Test1_Attribute_1 = some value
    Test1_Attribute _2 = some values
 Test2
    Test2_Attribute1 = some value
    Test2_Attribute2 = some value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613404/how-to-map-relational-database-to-owl).

Answer (score 1):

Information on RDBMS to RDF conversion:

1. [W3C Direct Mapping](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdb-direct-mapping/)
2. [W3C R2RML](https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/)
3. [Survey](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/96b2/3780cf17e06aaeb666b653420acc6c5228c6.pdf)

Some potential tools that can achieve this are:

1. [Antidot](https://github.com/antidot/db2triples).
2. [D2RQ](http://d2rq.org/)